# How to solve the vulnerabilities in react while updating dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, tailwind-css, npm-vulnerabilities

Even after using npm audit fix --force i am getting vulnerabilities and i am not able to remove them.

I need to update the dependencies for installing tailwindcss.
Here are some of them,
nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error